# Ackermann Steering and Arduino Servo Control

Tags: ros, teb-local-planner, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using this [package](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Servo%20Controller) to control some servo motors for an ackermann steered vehicle.

The local path planner that i am using is the [teb_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner)

I am wondering, how do I combine the two to achieve a complete ackermann steered system?

I have already implemented teb with a differential drive robot, but I am not sure what to do to send proper steering commands to the servo motors to achieve local path planning.

Please help,
Aaron

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295065/ackermann-steering-and-arduino-servo-control/) by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 135 on 2018-06-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ricardo Angeli](https://answers.ros.org/users/34859/ricardo-angeli/) on 2018-06-22**:
Can you describe with detail what each of your servos are doing?  Before using a path planner (like teb_local_planner) you will need an ackermann steering controller.  This subscribes to Geometry Twist messages and publishes Odometry messages.  Will this be within ROS or will the arduino do it?

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-23**:
The servo motors are used in a rack and pinion set up to push/pull a wheel in/out for steering. From my understanding, ROS should send a steering angle command and the arduino is only responsible for realizing this command for the servos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You use the teb_local_planner with move_base.
http://wiki.ros.org/move_base
move_base will publish a twist message.

The teb_local_planner can publish a steering angle in the twist msg. https://github.com/rst-tu-dortmund/teb_local_planner/blob/kinetic-devel/cfg/TebLocalPlannerReconfigure.cfg#L115

You will need a ROS node that convert steering angle of the twist to steering angles of each of your wheels.

Some code to help you : https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/melodic-devel/four_wheel_steering_controller/src/four_wheel_steering_controller.cpp#L437

---

Originally posted by [Vincent R](https://answers.ros.org/users/85/vincent-r/) with karma: 365 on 2018-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3